# How to compute effectively string length of cell array of strings

Tags: string, matlab

I have a cell array in Matlab:

```
strings = {'one', 'two', 'three'};
```

How can I efficiently calculate the length of all three strings? Right now I use a for loop:

```
lengths = zeros(3,1);
for i = 1:3
    lengths(i) = length(strings{i});
end
```

This is however unusable slow when you have a large amount of strings (I've got 480,863 of them). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also use:

```
cellfun(@length, strings)
```

It will not be faster, but makes the code clearer.
Regarding the slowness, you should first run the profiler to check where the bottleneck is. Only then should you optimize.

**Edit**: I just recalled that **'length'** used to be a built-in function in cellfun in older Matlab versions. So it might actually be faster! Try

```
 cellfun('length',strings)
```

**Edit(2)** : I have to admit that my first answer was a wild guess. Following @Rodin s comment, I decided to check out the speedup.

Here is the code of the benchmark:

First, the code that generates a lot of strings and saves to disk:

```
function GenerateCellStrings()
    strs = cell(1,10000);
    for i=1:10000
        strs{i} = GenerateRandomString();
    end
    save strs;
end

function st = GenerateRandomString()
    MAX_STR_LENGTH = 1000;
    n = randi(MAX_STR_LENGTH);
    st = char(randi([97 122], 1,n ));

end
```

Then, the benchmark itself:

```
 function CheckRunTime()
    load strs;
    tic;
    disp('Loop:');
    for i=1:numel(strs)
        n = length(strs{i});
    end
    toc;

    disp('cellfun (String):');
    tic;
    cellfun('length',strs);
    toc;

    disp('cellfun (function handle):');
    tic;
    cellfun(@length,strs);
    toc;

end
```

And the results are:

> Loop:
>   Elapsed time is **0.010663** seconds.
>   cellfun (String):
>   Elapsed time is **0.000313** seconds.
>   cellfun (function handle):
>   Elapsed time is **0.006280** seconds.

***Wow!!*** The 'length' syntax is about 30 times faster than a loop! I can only guess why it becomes so fast. Maybe the fact that it recognizes `length` specifically. Might be JIT optimization.

**Edit(3)** - I found out [the reason](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/cellfun-undocumented-performance-boost/) for the speedup. It is indeed recognition of `length` specifically. Thanks to @reve_etrange for the info.

Comment: that method eliminates the for loop and is very, very quick on my huge collection of strings. Thank you!

Comment: `cellfun('length', strings)` gives an error (not enough input arguments.) `cellfun('@length', strings)` works fine.

Comment: the `cellfun` syntax is much faster than the for loop because it eliminates the iterator variable and the constant lookup of `strs{i}`, which will completely bog down the system. This is why vectorization of your Matlab code is so important!

Comment: @Andrey asked for an explanation in an unrelated question. The reason for the performance increase when using the predefined function name strings with `cellfun` is that the (old, original) `cellfun` code has explicit code paths for those functions. [Undocumented MATLAB](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/cellfun-undocumented-performance-boost/) has a post about [the behavior](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html) (see "backwards compatibility").

Comment: @reve_etrange, thanks a lot! I will merge this info into my answer. Too bad comment votes don't count for rep. :)

Answer (score 2):

Keep an array of the lengths of said strings, and update that array when you update the strings. This will allow you O(1) time access to string lengths. Since you are updating it at the same time you generate or load strings, it shouldn't slow things down much, since integer array operations are (generally) faster than string operations.

Comment: The cell array is stored as a mat file, so calculating the string lengths upon loading is not really an option.