# how to sort a cell array which includes arrays?

Tags: matlab

I would like to sort a cell array according to one of the columns. The array is created by textscan function. There are some answers on web, but I still cannot get it working. I have the following array:

```
>> DATA

DATA = 

    {303427x1 cell}    {303427x1 cell}    {303427x1 cell}    {303427x1 cell}    [303427x1 uint32]    [303427x1 double]    [303427x1 uint32]    [303427x1 int32]    {303427x1 cell}
```

Important is the sixth column, which are times converted by datenum function. I want to sort the whole DATA by this column but with the link to another columns.
Normal sort or sortrows doesnt work for me. Could you help me please?

Comment: What was the original format of your date strings?  Have you verified the `datenum` output is good?

Comment: format was YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, the output of datenum is correct, I checked it.

Comment: You can mark an answer "accepted" by clicking the check mark icon to the left of the answer text.

Answer (score 2):

I take it you want to sort within each cell of `DATA`, correct?  The `datenum` function produces serial time stamps since "year zero," so they can be sorted normally.

```
times = DATA{6};
[~,idx] = sort(times,'ascend');
for i=1:length(DATA)
    DATA{i} = DATA{i}(idx);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid for-loop in @reve_etrange's answer by using CELLFUN after you get the sorting index `idx`.

```
DATA = cellfun(@(x) x(idx), DATA, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Comment: Just a note, `cellfun` does let you fit the code on one line, but it simply wraps the loop and adds a little overhead (it doesn't parallelize in any way).  Ultimately just a style choice.

Comment: @reve_etrange - check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881735/how-to-compute-effectively-string-length-of-cell-array-of-strings/8881819#8881819. cellfun can be much faster in some cases.

Comment: @Andrey - Only with a predefined list of functions, which can be passed to `cellfun` as strings.  See the "backwards compatibility" section of the documentation.

Comment: @reve_etrange, thanks for the info! By the way, do you have any idea why the 'length' syntax faster than @length? (See the linked answer above).

Comment: both suggestion works for me, thanks to both of you. I cant compare what is better