# Character count of regular expression in cells in MATLAB

Tags: regex, matlab, cell-array

Earlier I got some help as to how to make a script that will extract hashtags from a list of tweets and put them into an array of cells.
I used this as my code, inside a for loop

```
hashtagCell{i} = regexp(textRead{i}, '#[A-z]*', 'match');
```

This works for what it is supposed to do, but now I'm trying to find the average character length of the hashtags, so I need to be able to add the character length of each hashtag pulled out by the above function and add them together. However, when I try to use the size() function, it just gives me the size of the cell instead of the size of the strings, which is what I want. I can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help (and it gets rid of any loops, other than, perhaps, the one used to create `CellOfText`):

```
%# Example cell array of tweets
CellOfText = {'Bah #humbug says #Mr scrooge'; 'No #presents for you'};

%# Get all hash tags
HTC = regexp(CellOfText, '#[A-z]*', 'match');

%# Get the average hash tag length, being careful to unnest HTC
AvgLength1 = mean(cellfun('length', [HTC{:}]));
```

DISCLAIMER: The inspiration for this method came from [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881735/how-to-compute-effectively-string-length-of-cell-array-of-strings) to a similar question. Thanks to @Andrey for that.

Comment: I see what you're doing here, and it's helpful because I was not familiar with this function. However, I can only get this to work with one cell array of strings, and in my case, I have 30 that I need to average out. I think if I could put all of these into one large string I'd be golden.

Comment: @user1902116 I've got a loop-less solution for you that should work now. Let me know if it doesn't. The trick is in the `[HTC{:}]` line, which essentially un-nests the cells

Comment: @user1902116 No probs, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

For a single string it would be like this:

```
%# example string with hashtags.
MyText = 'this is a #text with #hashtag and also #another hashtag';

%# create the hashtagCell.
hashtagCell = regexp(MyText, '#[A-z]*', 'match');

%# compute the mean.
AverageLength = mean(cellfun(@(x) size(x,2), hashtagCell));
```

Comment: +1 for providing the appropriate `regexp`. I'm fairly sure my (or rather, @Andrey) method for getting the average length will run faster than yours though :-) Check out the link I provide for an interesting read on the subject.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is working.
EDIT: It actually didn't work for me. I'm sure it would if I could make this all into a single string.

Comment: @user1902116 If it works for you, you are encouraged to accept the answer by clicking on the sign on the left side of the answer, so that it changes its color to green.

Comment: It turns out it did not work for me though, which is why I held off on that.

Comment: @user1902116 Please post a short example input (as a MATLAB command to define it), because cell arrays come in many sizes and dimensions.