# Counting occurrences of a character in a string within a cell

Tags: matlab

I'm having trouble figuring out how to count the occurrences of a character in a string within a cell. For example, I have a file that contains information like so:

```
type
m
mmNs
SmNm
```

and I'm trying to determine how many m's are in each line. To do this, I've tried this code:

```
sampleddata = dataset('file','sample.txt','Delimiter','\t');
muts = sampleddata.type;
fileID = fopen('number_occur.txt','w');
for j = 1:3
    mutations = muts(j)
    M = length(find(mutations == 'm'));
    fprintf(fileID, '%1f\n',M)
end
fclose(fileID)
```

However, I get an error that informs me: "Undefined operator '==' for input arguments of type 'cell'." Does anyone know how to overcome this problem?

Comment: in your line mutations == 'm'; the == only works for numerics in matrices, you need to use a `regexp` for string matches. Basically, use `regexp` for each line, find how many 'm' there are and return count.

Comment: @GameOfThrows Thank you. I'll look into this.

Comment: No problem, I would recommend reading this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871716/character-count-of-regular-expression-in-cells-in-matlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gonna post a result here in case you did not find a way to do it. There are loads of ways to do it, I am just going to put one of them.

Basically, you want a regex to do string matches:

```
a = {'type';
'm';
'mmNs';
'SmNm';
'mmmmM'} %//Load in Data,
pattern = 'm'; %//The pattern you are looking for is 'm', it could be anything really, a number of specific word or a specific pattern
lines = regexp(a, pattern, 'tokens'); %// look for this pattern in each line
result = cellfun('length',lines); %//count the size of matched patterns, so each time it matches, the size should increase by 1.
```

This gives the result in a matrix form:

```
result =

 0
 1
 2
 2
 4
```

Comment: Yes. This worked. Thank you for the suggestion! It might actually work better for my future analysis than what I found.